# Can i use different SocksPorts than 9050?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

Socksv5, SOCKS HOST 127.0.0.1, Port 9050

I use this Network Setting with Mozilla Firefox.

But even though i use different Useragents for each Firefox Profile, 
through the configuration of the about:config, does it not change the Ip Adress.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can change the socks port, and you must change it in both your tor configuration and in your browser configuration. The user agent has nothing to do with the IP of your exit node, and if you change this you're probably making yourself easily fingerprintable. Tor uses per-socks-port stream isolation so you can use multiple socks ports, but it's probably easier to use a single socks port but with a different username for each of them.

Is there a reason you're not using the Tor Browser? It is specifically designed to take care of these things for you.

For details about Tor's configuration file, see the following two links:

https://support.torproject.org/tbb/tbb-editing-torrc/ (for the Tor Browser)
https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en

If you aren't already using a configuration file, you should make a new one somewhere with the desired settings, and then start tor using `tor -f path/to/torrc` You can find details about the `SocksPort` setting [here](https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#SocksPort).

Comment: And how can i change the socks port in my "tor configuration"? I only know that i have created an Windows Service at services.msc that starts tor.exe automatically at startup.

Comment: @Jacob: See the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's totally not hard-coded. The port for Socks is 1080 - as it is *usually* happens in the network setups. The port number 9050 is *just* a default in Tor. And - the Microsoft **so-called accidentally** has binded some system services on desktop operating systems on it to prevent Tor expert bundle working out of the box for inexperienced users. You - actually on Windows OS - **must** change it, for good. I'm using 9999, but pick any available one of your choice. Even more - on Linux and Unix OS'es you can try utilizing a Unix FSock(file sockets) - it will lower a payload for the network operations on localhost.